# git merge ignoring new files

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm working on a project and using git as my versioning tool.

The project has 2 branches: release and production.

The release branch is merged into production.

On the latest merge I've have across a weird behavior.

There is a folder called 'my_folder' on the project. It's contents on the "release" branch are:

```
my_folder/
    a_file
    settings
```

whilst on production branch

```
my_folder/
    a_file
```

The odd thing is, when I do a `git checkout production` followed by `git merge release`, the file "settings" is not brought into 'my_folder' even though any changes performed into 'a_file' done on release branch are applied on production branch.

This may be a bit confusing so I'll try to illustrate what happens in another way

initial state:

**release branch**

```
my_folder/
    a_file /*release_version*/
    settings
```

**production branch**

```
    my_folder/
        a_file /*production_version*/
```

after performing a `git merge release`

**production branch**

```
    my_folder/
        a_file /*release_version*/
        /*settings file missing here*/
```

My production branch is still missing the settings file that should have been created after the merge.

Any clue on why this is happening?

Comment: Is `settings` committed?

Comment: yes. It's commited on the release branch

Comment: Is settings present in `git merge-base release production` and subsequently removed in production?

Comment: well. I really can't say for sure, since I'm not the only person working on the project. But I believe it is possible that happened. The release branch was originally used as production, than development, and now it's finally being given proper user. Which means that may have occurred a switch around in files.